# Where to find database connections in an Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, database-connection

New to Android app building.  I built our company website using php/mysql and my boss had an android app built previously with, I assume SQLlite, or something.  Anyway, he wants me to change the database that it's currently linked with to our mysql db.  For the life of me I cannot find anything even resembling a connection string or a query in the file system?  In my attached screenshot where would I find this information? Or is it not held in this tree at all?

I would assume the data/model folders, but I've searched every single file in those folders.  I really need some help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is a local db.  There would be no connection string, its literally accessed as part of your process.

You should NOT directly connect to a remote db.  Doing so is completely insecure, as it would be putting the password for your db into the app.  You need to run a web service, and hit that to get your data.  The web service then connects to the db.

You should also probably figure out what the actual project is.  With SQLite, you would work offline, based off a copy of the data stored locally.  With a remote db, offline use is impossible.  Being told to replace SQLite with a remote db and your level of understanding of that in this question shows that one or both of you don't understand what the scope of that change is, and you should make sure you're on the same page and what the best way to achieve the actual goal of your project is.

Comment: Haha I agree but my boss doesn't really work like this unfortunately.  Just wants things done when he thinks of them..  Well he had an india team and says the db is held in Azure so it might actually be remote and not SQLlite right now?  I just don't even know where to start.  I'm hired as a PHP dev and now he expects me to build and fix this Android app which I have zero experience doing.  I do appriciate the help though.  I know my question is vague, but I just do not know where to even start.  Thanks